# Can't set older Microsoft Office version as default (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, file-association

I have a version of Microsoft Office 2013 that is registered, and a newer one, Office 365, that isn't. In the program folder, the older version is in `Microsoft Office/Office15` and the newer is in `Microsoft Office/root/Office16`.

The newer version is opening every file and application by default, which brings up a plethora of popups reminding me that my copy of Office is unregistered, and I can't use features. For obvious reasons, I want to use the version that actually lets me use Office programs for their intended purposes.

I have tried the following:

- Right click on a file > Open With > select the version under `Office15`. It still opens using the newer version.
- Going into Default App Settings and trying to change default behavior by file type. The older version does not appear.
- Uninstalling the newer version. It attempts to uninstall ALL versions of Office.

I do not remember my credentials for the version of Microsoft Office that I'm using, so I want to avoid uninstalling everything if possible.

Is there any way to force this to work?

Comment: Can you be specific about which versions of Office you have installed?  In whatever scenario you fix this problem, it's going to require those credentials, so you need to figure that problem out.

Comment: The older is 2013, the newer is 365. Added that info to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a broken install of office, i would run the office repair tool for office 365 and then set items to open with office 2013.
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b

I would most definitely reset your office account password pre-hand. if you open office and click on account it will show you which account it is activated via, you can then reset the password for that account and access your Microsoft account.
Warning: repairing office may trigger it to have you reactivate office.